# Check for nil in data before saving to CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uialertcontroller

I have this code below that when run I'd like it to check and see if the fields itemName, itemNote, etc are empty and if so display UIAlertController and prevent the user from continuing. The code that I'm attempting to use is under the saveTapped IBAction function. Currently, in runtime it seems to bypass all the checking and goes directly to the "if(item != nil) {" check.

Any insight would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddEditViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var item : Item? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var itemName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var itemNote: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var hoursPlayed: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var imageHolder: UIImageView!

let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if item != nil {
        itemName.text = item?.name
        itemNote.text = item?.note
        hoursPlayed.text = item?.hoursPlayed
        imageHolder.image = UIImage(data: (item?.image)!)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func AddImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    pickerController.allowsEditing = true

    self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func addImageFromCamera(sender: AnyObject) {
    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    pickerController.allowsEditing = true

    self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    self.imageHolder.image = image
}

@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    var nameMissing = ""

    if itemName == nil {
        nameMissing = "name"
        print("item missing")
    }
    else if itemNote == nil {
        nameMissing = "note"
        print("note missing")
    }
    else if hoursPlayed == nil {
        nameMissing = "hours played"
        print("hours played missing")
    }
    else if imageHolder == nil {
        nameMissing = "image"
        print("image missing")
    }

    if (itemName == nil || itemNote == nil || hoursPlayed == nil || imageHolder == nil) {
        let missingDetailsAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Complete field for \(nameMissing).", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        missingDetailsAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(missingDetailsAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    if(item != nil) {
        editItem()
    } else {
        createNewItem()
    }
    dismissViewController()
}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewController()
}

func dismissViewController() {
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}

func createNewItem() {
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("item", inManagedObjectContext: moc)

    let item = Item(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)

    item.name = itemName.text
    item.note = itemNote.text
    item.hoursPlayed = hoursPlayed.text
    item.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)

    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        print("Create Save Failed.")
        return
    }
}

func editItem() {
    item?.name = itemName.text
    item?.note = itemNote.text
    item?.hoursPlayed = hoursPlayed.text
    item!.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)

    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        print("Edit Save Failed.")
        return
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for `text` property of your `textFields` not for `nil`.
Try this:

```
if let name = itemName.text where name.characters.count > 0 {
   //show your alert
} else if let note = itemNote.text where note.characters.count > 0 {
  //show your alert
} else if let hours = hoursPlayed.text where hours.characters.count > 0 {
  //show your alert
} else if let image = imageHolder.image {
   //show your alert
}
```

And if you want to access the value without alert then you could try this also for `UITextFields`:

```
let name = itemName.text ?? ""
let note = itemNote.text ?? ""
let hours = hoursPlayed.text ?? ""
```

Comment: Ah thanks, for checking the image, would I need to use CGSize or something else?

Comment: CGSize for what? I didn't get your point, can you please elaborate it?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to detect if an image exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

## No need to do extra code every time

Use this simple code for check empty string

```
let bananaName = "       "  //Empty String

let mango = "Mango"


//Make file for this function and call like my example below return Boolean value for check the value

//Function
struct Checker {

    static func isEmptyfor(content:String) -> Bool? {

        guard content.trimString.isEmpty else {
            print("Not Empty")
            return true
        }

        print("Empty")
        return false
    }

}

// String Extenion here for Validate trim String
extension String {
    var trimString:String {
       return  self.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    }
}

//***Final Code here for use this Only for check your string

//Call Function here Like This
//##exp 1
if Checker.isEmptyfor(bananaName)! {
    print("Not Empty")
   //Do something here

}else{
    print("Empty")
}

//##exp 2
if Checker.isEmptyfor(mango)! {
    print("Not Empty")
  //Do something here

}else{
    print("Empty")
}
```

### Output of the code inside Playground

[image]